# jupyter notebook keyerror: 148 on running lambda

Tags: python, arrays, jupyter-notebook

I've been trying to learn an old github post, I have fixed most problems:

```
def create_location_count(features):
    for feat in features:
        loc_count = data.pivot_table(values=feat, index='location',aggfunc=lambda x: sum(x>0))
        data['loc_count_%s'%feat] = data['location'].apply(lambda x: loc_count[x])

def create_location_stats(features):
    for feat in features:
        loc_mean = data.pivot_table(values=feat, index='location',aggfunc=lambda x: np.mean([i for i in x if i>0]) if sum(x>0)>0 else 0)
        data['loc_mean_%s'%feat] = data['location'].apply(lambda x: loc_mean[x])
```

and when I run it (in a Jupyter notebook):

```
new_feat = ['feature 203','feature 82','feature 170','feature 54',
        'feature 201','feature 80','feature 71','feature 193','feature 54','feature 312','feature 202',
        'feature others_1','feature 232','feature 68', 'feature others_0','feature 307']
create_location_stats(new_feat)
```

I get this error: `KeyError: 148`

Comment: Im 100% sure the error is from made by 
data['loc_mean_%s'%feat]

Comment: `def create_location_count(features):
    for feat in features:
        loc_count = data.pivot_table(values=feat, index='location',aggfunc=lambda x: sum(x>0))
        data['loc_count_%s'%feat] = data['location'].apply(lambda x: iloc.loc_count[x])`

I needed to add iloc

Answer (score 0):

I think your number one suspect is `data['location'].apply(lambda x: loc_count[x])` where you are using the elements of `location` (possibly integers) to index `loc_count`. The same thing happens in the next for loop.

The produced KeyError states that `loc_count` does not contain key 148.

I hope these tips help you!